# Is it possible to convert a batch of WGS84 to SWEREF coordinates?

Tags: geoserver, coordinates

I have a problem considering converting a batch of coordinates. I need to convert from WGS84 into SWEREF

Is it possible to convert a batch?

Comment: what does geoserver have to do with this question? What have you tried? What were the results of that?

Comment: What accuracy on the "WGS84" coordinates? Are they really ITRF, and if so, what's the epoch? Here's [one document](https://www.lantmateriet.se/globalassets/kartor-och-geografisk-information/gps-och-matning/geodesi/transformationer/pm_transf_itrf_sweref99_090817.pdf) with a transformation.